# ¿Alguien me puede responder el cómo funciona este código?[recursividad]

Tags: c#

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(p1.PotenciaRecursiva(2, 6));
}

public int PotenciaRecursiva(int n, int p)
{
    if (p==0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return n * PotenciaRecursiva(n,p-1);
    }
}
```

> OUTPUT: 64

Answer (score 6):

El código hace algo similar a un bucle, la variable p funciona como un contador, desde p que es la potencia a la que quieres elevar el número, hasta 0. Mientras p va decrementando su valor, la función retorna n * la función llamada nuevamente, pasando como argumentos n y el valor de p menos 1:

Si por ejemplo, tienes n = 2 y p = 3, lo que hace es lo siguiente:

> Como 3 (nuestra p) no es igual a 0, voy a devolver el valor 2 * el valor que retorne la función de 2 (nuestro n) a la 2 (nuestra p menos 1).

Como la función es llamada nuevamente, se repite lo de arriba, "apilándose" hasta llegar a p=0:

> Como 2 (nuestra p) no es igual a 0, voy a devolver el valor 2 * el valor que retorne la función de 2 (nuestro n) a la 1 (nuestra p menos 1).
>
> Como 1 (nuestra p) no es igual a 0, voy a devolver el valor 2 * el valor que retorne la función de 2 (nuestro n) a la 0 (nuestra p menos 1).

Ah! Pero ahora p es igual a 0, entonces ahora, no retorna 2 * ..., sino que retorna 1. Entonces, la pila armada de returns desde 2 a la 3, quedaría algo así:

```
1 --> cuando p = 0
2 * el valor de arriba --> cuando p = 1
2 * el valor de arriba --> cuando p = 2 
2 * el valor de arriba --> cuando p = 3

2 * 1 = 2 --> cuando p = 1
2 * el valor de arriba --> cuando p = 2
2 * el valor de arriba --> cuando p = 3

2 * 2 = 4  --> cuando p = 2
2 * el valor de arriba --> cuando p = 3

2 * 4 = 8  --> cuando p = 3
```

Por lo tanto, 2 a la 3 es igual a 8.

Lo mismo es con 2 a la 6, pero el "2 * el valor de arriba" se repetiría 3 veces más.

Lo más sencillo cuando no entiendes un algoritmo es hacer una prueba de escritorio.

Saludos!